# How to run jruby script from MRI ruby rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I have a script written with jRuby and I need this script to be executed from rails app (which runs on MRI ruby). I have code like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def run_script!
    system "jruby /path/to/my/script/script.rb #{id}"
  end
end
```

and it works in development! But on Ubuntu production server it returns `nil` and I have no idea how to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

From the `Kernel#system` [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system):

> Returns nil if command execution fails. An error status is available in $?.

So what does `$?` tell you?

Comment: exit 127

Seems like I don't have jruby in my PATH

Comment: If I specify the path to jruby I get this: `Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.
`

Comment: @makaroni4: What dependencies does `script.rb` have and how are you managing them?

Comment: Just require 'java', I solved my problem moving jRuby code to daemon, it is much more clearer than execute script from MRI Rails app imho